# Fictional Sci-Fi Dates Calendar?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, online-resources

Is there any kind of online database, that features calendar of dates from sci-fi books/movies etc. Not sci-fi real life events calendar, but something similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2155) for example, but more detailed

Comment: Good one. I wouldn't mind seeing something like your Wikipedia link, only for past decades. I mean, there's nothing specifically on Wikipedia about, for instance, "1990s in SF".

Comment: The [Grand Unified Timeline](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GrandUnifiedTimeline) on TVTropes is an attempt at something like this (though it's both huge and absurdly incomplete).

Answer (score 12):

**No. Such a master historical database of science fiction hasn't been created and I can't imagine anyone would attempt to do so without an amazing motivation because of the number of books that already exist, never mind the tens of thousands that appear every year.**

Fan attempts at various types of timelines have existed, such as:

- The [**Grand Unified Timeline**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GrandUnifiedTimeline) is a TVtropes attempt at gathering a wide array of events in an uncontrolled fashion and placing them on a timeline. This is the closest representation I have seen. Looking through the comic section I found it to be fairly accurate and as complete as comicbooks allow. (Found by [Micah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6217/micah) and added for completeness.)

[image]

- [Historical Timeline of the DC Universe](http://dcuniverseonline.wikia.com/wiki/Historical_Timeline): first compiled by fans and later ratified by DC Comics, this timeline lists events across the very jumbled temporal history of the DCU.
- [The Known Space Project](http://www.chronology.org/niven/) which attempts to chronicle all of Larry Niven's work in the Known Space sagas.
- [The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen wiki](http://lxg.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline), which compiles all of the publications of the League and any extraneous printed matter into a cohesive timeline.
- [the Marvel Chronology Project](http://www.chronologyproject.com/) is an ongoing attempt to track the entire temporal history of the Marvel Universe including its alternative timelines and histories.
- [The Tarzan/John Carter/Pellucidar/Caspak/Moon/Carson of Venus Chronology](http://pjfarmer.com/woldnewton/Tarzan_Chron.pdf) which is a fan attempt to connect these pulp age stories into a single cohesive temporal framework.
- Ward Shelley painted the "[History of Science Fiction](http://www.wardshelley.com/paintings/newpaintings4.html)" and it detailed both the tales of science fiction as well as the creator history of when science fiction stories were being created. It doesn't list dates as such, just the progression of tales as they moved into the future and separates the types of fiction.

[image]

- You can see that certain tales are chronologically expected to appear after certain others.
- Visually quite stunning, it has never been duplicated in a database fashion as far as I can tell.

**Fan favorites have always kept timelines of various sorts. Star Trek is known for its timelines of the Federation across shows.**

[image]

- Fan efforts have even tracked exotic timelines such as which Trek heroes have traveled to what eras across time.

[image]

**Other fan timelines include keeping track of technology first theorized and then later created in the real world:**

[image]

- This graphic shows predictions for particular technologies in science fiction and when they became a reality. (Click for detail!)

Comment: Why is HAL attributed to HHGG? (Great answer, btw.)

Comment: Thank you. It's not HAL per se, it's the voice activated computer (or so it says).